# Build Failed: Couldn't find an executable for CC? Kivy, Buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I want to build an app with buildozer.

I get the following error message:

```
[INFO]:    # Prebuilding recipes
[INFO]:    Prebuilding hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    hostpython3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for hostpython3[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    hostpython3 already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding libffi for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    libffi has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for libffi[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    libffi already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding openssl for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    openssl has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_image for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_image has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_image[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_image already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_mixer for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for sdl2_mixer[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    sdl2_mixer already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2_ttf for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2_ttf has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sqlite3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sqlite3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding python3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    python3 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for python3[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    python3 already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    sdl2 has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    setuptools has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    six has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    pyjnius has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for pyjnius[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    pyjnius already patched, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding android for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    android has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/jetson/dd/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/android-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/jetson/dd/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Prebuilding kivy for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    kivy has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    # Building recipes
[INFO]:    Building hostpython3 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    hostpython3 said it is already built, skipping
[INFO]:    Building libffi for armeabi-v7a
[ERROR]:   Build failed: Couldn't find executable for CC. This indicates a problem locating the /home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-aarch64/bin/clang executable in the Android NDK, not that you don't have a normal compiler installed. Exiting.
Searching path are: '/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-aarch64/bin:/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c:/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/jetson/dd/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'de_DE.UTF-8'
#     MANAGERPID = '6530'
#     DISPLAY = ':1'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '2e39730d7cfb41bc9a93b16960d3548e'
#     GTK_CSD = '0'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     USERNAME = 'jetson'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     USER = 'jetson'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'unity'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/b6445d43_23e9_4946_9f30_7da5b647efaf'
#     PWD = '/home/jetson/dd'
#     HOME = '/home/jetson'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:34601'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/unity:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'unity'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'gnome-keyring'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     GNOME_SESSION_XDG_SESSION_PATH = ''
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity:Unity7:ubuntu'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.90'
#     SHLVL = '2'
#     GDMSESSION = 'unity'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'jetson'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-unity:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/jetson-desktop:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/6777,unix/jetson-desktop:/tmp/.ICE-unix/6777'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/jetson'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/jetson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
```

Buildozer failed to execute the last command.
The error might be hidden in the log above this error.
Please read the full log, and search for it before.
raising an issue with buildozer itself.
In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2.

Can anyone help me?